# How to make each method wait to complete another inside of parallel.Foreach?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a big problem for "parallel For" by using Task Parallel. I want to make my methods and functions synchronous (wait on each other).

```
Parallel.For(items, item=>
{
    var a = MyClass1.Function(foo.x);
    var b = MyClass2.Function(zoo.y, b.z);  ---> Should wait "a" result...
    var c = MyClass2.Method1(a.x,b.z); -----> Should wait b result...
});
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It already does what you want.

Comment: What's wrong with the result? Have you tried running the code? It will run as you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Parallel.For` will run in parallel across your collection of `items`. Each `item` it processes, will invoke the given delegate synchronously. Meaning, it will execute `MyClass1.Function` then `MyClass2.Function` then `MyClass2.Method1`. This is assuming your methods are synchronous, and you're not doing anything in background threads inside any of them.

Imagine it like this:

```
                Items
  |          |          |          |
 Item1:      Item2:     Item3:     Item4:
Function1  Function1  Function1  Function1
Function2  Function2  Function2  Function2
Method1    Method1    Method1    Method1
```